# How to create a simple input and output in pure Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript and am trying to write code for a simple greeting. The user will have an input box to type their name in to and below a button for them to click that outputs a value of "Hello {name}!". If you could help me out I would appreciate it!

Comment: Create ["Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and describe your problem in more details.

Answer (score 0):

You could start doing something like this:

```js
(function() {


  // Creates <input id="myTextBox" type="text" />
  var textBox = document.createElement("input");
  textBox.id = "myTextBox";
  textBox.type = "text";

  // Creates <button id="myButton" type="button">Show</button>
  var btnShow = document.createElement("button");
  btnShow.id = "myButton";
  btnShow.type = "button";
  btnShow.innerHTML = "Show";

  // When you click in the button, show the message.
  btnShow.onclick = function showMessage() {
    alert("Hello " + textBox.value + "!");
  };

  // Add created elements.
  document.body.appendChild(textBox);
  document.body.appendChild(btnShow);


})();
```

You can find more information about `createElement` function in this site: [Document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).